# How to fix Error: mkdir(): Permission denied when running composer

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, composer-php

I have a ec2 image and get the following error when trying to create a new laravel project.

> [ErrorException] mkdir(): Permission denied

Here is the command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel mydir
```

I can write to the folder with my ec2-user username but do I need to add permission for composer to write?

Comment: can  you use `sudo` ?

Comment: no, i get sudo: composer: command not found

Comment: composer is installed, if i run 'composer' i get the help documentation

Comment: try something like `sudo /usr/bin/composer create-project laravel/laravel mydir`

Comment: sudo: /usr/bin/composer: command not found

Comment: where did you install composer to?  `/usr/local/bin/composer` ?

Comment: I figured it out, it was an issue with the directory permissions. I followed this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Comment: Just change the permission to your directory `sudo chmod -R /path/to/your/directory`

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Quick Answer:**

For security reasons, lets keep `root` as the owner and just allow ourselves to read, write, and execute within the area which we will be working in.

1. Change directories

   > `cd /var/www/`
2. Change group ownership

   > `sudo chown -Rv root:$USER .`
3. Add priviledges to our group

   > `sudo chmod -Rv g+rw .`
4. For the grand finale, go ahead and create your new laravel project

   > `composer create-project laravel/laravel`projectName`--prefer-dist`

*Congratulations, We're done. :)*

**In-Depth Explanation**

*Explanation behind the solution:*
By default you have two users; `root` and `$USER`(this is the global variable, but the actual name is whatever you put as your username). Every user created comes with a group as well. So if my username is `john`, I have a group called `john`.
There are many ways to solve this problem but I perfer this route for a few reasons:

1. I still want `root` to be the owner of the files for security reason.
2. I am working in a localhost so there shouldn't be any other (guest)users writing on my files.

In order to achieve this we will need to edit the group ownership and add the proper permissions. We will leave the `others` as is and only allow them to read and execute the files.

So lets get started:

1. I like being in the directory that I am making changes to in order to avoid mistakes so first we will need to enter the the directory which we will be working in.

   > `cd /var/www/`
2. We will need to change the group ownership of the directories which we will be working in. Starting from the directory which we are in and all the future directories and files we will create underneath this directory. So basically any children directories from now on will be own by our group.

   > `sudo chown -Rv root:$USER .`

> > `chown` = command to **ch**ange **own**er.
> >
> > `-R` = Recursive - This is basically stating to perform the same command to all the directories within this directory.
> >
> > `-v` = verbose - we are stating here to keep us updated by showing us what is actually happening.
> >
> > `root:$USER` = This is were we are setting the ownership. The first word before the colon(:) states the `root` will be the single owner. The second word after the colon(:) states that the group owner will be `$USER`(the current user).
> >
> > `.` = This just means 'here, in this directory'.

3. Now we are going to add the right privileges to our group. Keep in mind this is where we allow `root` to be the primary owner while ONLY allowing ourself's to create changes(of course, besides `root`). As I mentioned before, this does not allow other users to create any changes what so ever.

   > `sudo chmod -Rv g+rw .`

> > `chmod` = command to **ch**ange **mod**ifications, in this case, privileges.
> >
> > `-Rv` = Recursive & Verbose
> >
> > `g` = this states who will receive the modifications. In our case g-group Other options are u-user and o-other.
> >
> > `+` = symbolizes add
> >
> > `r` = symbolizes read
> >
> > `w` = symbolizes write

4. Now we are done. Try creating a new laravel project.

   > `composer create-project laravel/laravel`projectName` --prefer-dist

**Note:** If this is not working, enter the command `ls -al | grep $USER` while inside the `/var/www/` directory.

If you get this:
`drwxrw-r-x`

You are missing the executable(`x`) privilege for the group. The first `x` is for the user and last `x` is for others. There should be middle `x` for the group.

Run the following command and you should be all set to go:

`sudo chmod -Rv g+x .`

Now if you run `ls -al | grep $USER`, you should get:

`drwxrwxr-x`

Comment: Thank you Oscar for this nice detailed explanation!

Comment: Work for me on Ubuntu server 18.04 for a Codeigniter4 installation via composer.

Comment: On MacOS I get `chown: constantsolutions: illegal group name`

Comment: On MacOS I had to create a new group had my current user was member of (I called it `devops`). Go to "Users & Groups" in Preferences and click the `+` icon, then select `Group` from the dropdown and call it whatever you want. Then run `sudo chown -Rv root:YOUR-GROUP-NAME .`

Answer (score 20):

1. add "www" group and add your user to this group

   ```
   sudo groupadd www
   sudo usermod -a -G www ec2-user
   ```
2. logout/login
3. set ownership and write permissions

   ```
   sudo chown -R root:www /var/www
   sudo chmod 2775 /var/www
   find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} +
   find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} +
   ```

Referencing: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Comment: Important to logout and login

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the similar ErrorException, when creating an additional project inside the Homestead/Vagrant environment. 
I had previously added folders and path to the Homestead.yaml.

The answers of Oscar and Jens A. Koch pointed into the right direction, but go too far on my dev-machine.

Working narrower solution inside Homestead-Box:

```
sudo mkdir <ProjectDir> 
sudo chgrp vagrant <ProjectDir>
sudo chmod g+wx <ProjectDir>
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <Project>
```

Comment: This worked for me and it was consistent with other laravel projects that were install and (somehow) had the same permissions.

Answer (score 2):

**The gist of the problem**

Installing Laravel inside `/var/www/html` folder is a common requirement. However, the system defaults usually sets the user and group for this folder and its parent(`www`) to `root` And `composer` will [complain](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-to-install-untrusted-packages-safely.md) if you run it as `root`.

**Solution**

- Find the user corresponding to your apache/nginx server. It usually has names like `www`,`www-data` etc. You can run the below command to get a clue

  ```
    cat /etc/group | grep www
  ```
- With the knowledge of the server user(from above), you can run the below commands. I am assuming that your server user is `www-data`

  ```
    # Under your user account, change directories
    cd /var/www/
    # Change group ownership
    sudo chown -Rv root:www-data .
    # Give all the privileges to the group
    sudo chmod -Rv g+rwx .
    # Add your user name to www-data group, use 'who' command to get your username
    sudo usermod -a -G www-data your_user_name
    # Verify that your user name is in the www-data group by typing
    group your_user_name
    # Very important, logout of the system and come back to this folder
    # Do the the laravel install
    composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectName
    # Not finished yet! recursive make the www-data the group owner of projecName which the folder in which Laravel site resides by now
    sudo chown -R :www-data projectName
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have read/write folder permission. It works to me.

Like in ubuntu

```
 var/www/html
```

So if you want to make dir in `html` folder then first give permission to `html` folder. Then you are done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This Problem with a **Vagrant** box

If you tried to install something with composer in a new vagrant box, it is possible that when installing the vagrant you have specified the path you are allowed to use.

So check your personal .yml file in order to check this under 
\ansible\vars

there you have something like this

```
vagrant_local:
  vm:
    name: oxideshop
    hostname: oxideshop.local
    aliases:
      - www.oxideshop.local
    app_shared_folder:
      source: oxideshop
      target: /var/www/oxideshop
```

You have to make sure, that the app_shared_folder target is the same you use for the composer installation.

**Example:**

> composer create-project oxid-esales/oxideshop-project
>   **/var/www/oxideshop** dev-b-6.1-ce

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have read/write folder permission.
LIKE: sudo chown -R USER NAME:www-data /PROJECT PATH/USER NAME/PROJECT NAME/

Example:

```
$ sudo chown -R tubai:www-data /home/tubai/firstlara/
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands

```
cd /var/www

sudo chown -R $USER:www-data html/

sudo chmod -R 775 html/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and executing the command using **sudo** just worked for me:

```
sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel mydir
```

Answer (score -3):

cd to the directory where you currently want to install laravel and change directory access with

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./
```

type your password and you are good to resume to the installation

Comment: Please consider the following link in regards to why 777 permissions are a bad idea: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777