# Problems setting up laravel

Tags: php, laravel, macos, command-line, composer-php

Laravel's command doesn't work for me.

```
laravel  new potato
-bash: laravel: command not found
```

I have already installed composer, vendor, and laravel.

I edited the path with nano

```
sudo nano ~/.bash_profile
```

I put the path from laravel, I was following the Laracast's tutorial

```
export $Path = $HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin
```

It doesn't work for me
I search same info and they say to use

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"
```

And after that use

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: have you installed laravel globally?

Comment: I think so, i used  this command ``composer global require laravel/installer``

Comment: verify it again by installing laravel globally and if problem still persists try clearing composer cache by `composer clearcache`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel <<project_directory>> --prefer-dist
```

Comment: I get this error
 [ErrorException]            
  mkdir(): Permission denied

Comment: Looks like you have directory permission issues. Try adding sudo in front of it:  sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel <<project_directory>> --prefer-dist

Comment: I got this: Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details

Comment: This is possible solution for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266250/how-to-fix-error-mkdir-permission-denied-when-running-composer