# What is the correct place to put my website files var/www or lampp/htdocs

Tags: laravel, composer-php, chown, kali-linux

I faced a "mkdir(): permission denied" problem when creating a new laravel project via composer by 
`composer create-project laravel/laravel lsapp` command, so I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266250/how-to-fix-error-mkdir-permission-denied-when-running-composer) solution. 
It said to change the group ownership by `sudo chown -Rv root:$USER .` but he was doing this to `cd var/www/`, so this make me wondering if he did this because he put his files into `/var/www/` so I should execute the command on `/opt/lampp/htdocs/` .
or I should execute the command on `/var/www/` regardless which directory I use to put my files.

And finally what is the usual directory people used to put their laravel project into ?

**update:**

I try to change the ownership to both directories so now I know that the command executed to your directory, now the question still what is the best place to put my laravel project, and if I choose `/var/www/` how can I open it from the browser with `/localhost`

Answer (score 1):

You need to point your apache .conf file to where ever your files are stored. Here is an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000> 
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/myproject/public/"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "/var/www/myproject/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This project will be at "localhost:8000"

If your project is not stored in "var/www", then just change those parameters in this block of your conf file in your apache configuration. This can be found in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/myproject.conf` (on linux)

Comment: I set DocumentRoot to "/var/www/public/"
and Directory "/var/www/"> but whenever I go to localhost, it takes me to localhost/dashboard which mean that it still take me to /opt/lampp/htdocs/

Comment: May be I should hint that there isn't myproject.conf in the directory you specified, no conf file to my project specifically, there is only 000-default.conf

Comment: and also <VirtualHost *:80> not 8000, and when I changed it to 8000 and write in browser localhost:8000 it said "unable to connect", and when I return it back to 80 it takes me to localhost/dashboard

Comment: I think this link might help you more: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-laravel-on-ubuntu-for-apache/