# Permission denied when creating a laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel example-app
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./example-app"
Installing laravel/laravel (v8.6.10)

[ErrorException]
mkdir(): Permission denied

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [] [] []

Comment: im using xampp on linux

Comment: what is the full path you are trying to use?

Comment: try 'sudo php composer.phar create-project laravel/laravel example-app'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Error: mkdir(): Permission denied when running composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266250/how-to-fix-error-mkdir-permission-denied-when-running-composer)

Answer (score -2):

Solved by command
sudo chmod 777 'dir-name'

Comment: Note for future readers, don't do this. It's a terrible idea. You should instead properly set permissions and ownership of your laravel folder.